# Multithreading with Vaadin

Tags: java, multithreading, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am trying to shift a process in another thread and the process is completed successfully, but unable to open a notification popup from a different thread to a UI. The log in run method with here message is displayed. But notification is not showing up.

```
public class CreateSnapshotView extends VerticalLayout {
   private void testView(CreateSnapshot snapshot) {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(new Label("Open Moves for ");
    dialog.add(new CreateSnapshotConfirmOpenMovesView(snapshot, new CreateSnapshotConfirmOpenMovesView.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void yes(CreateSnapshot snapshot) {
            
            User user = (User) UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute("user");
            UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
    
            TestService testService = new TestService(snapshot,user,ui);
            Thread thread = new Thread(testService);
            thread.start();
            dialog.close();
        }

    }));
    dialog.setWidth("500px");
    dialog.setCloseOnOutsideClick(false);
    dialog.open();

}


public class TestService implements Runnable {

  private User user;
  private CreateSnapshot snapshot;
  private DalResponse response;
  private final UI ui;

  public TestService(CreateSnapshot snapshot, User user, UI ui){
      this.snapshot = snapshot;
      this.user = user;
      this.ui = ui;
  }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      DalResponse response = AppView.cycleCountService.deleteCreateSnapshot(user, snapshot);

        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            log.info("UI test:" + ui);
            log.info("here");
            ui.access(() -> Notification.show("Completed"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you anabled push? This is required, since these are "server initiated" UI updates

Comment: Ohh yes, yeah it worked with enabling push. Thanks for your help 